# Look for text with BeautifulSoup in a web page with multiple html tags?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Thanks for your help.

I am trying to extract text from a web page using BeautifulSoup and Python.
I have done it lots of times with different web pages and always got the information I needed, but this time the html source code from the web page has a lot of scripts and other stuff. This is one of the pages I want to extract information from:

http://www.cofemersimir.gob.mx/mirs/38656

The problem with this web page is that it has a lot of iframe tags, each of which has an opening tag (html) and a closing one (/html) and I can extract information from the main page but not the information hidden on the second tab and under the hidden display text area.

For example, when I look for:

```
soup.find('div',{'name':"Pregunta_452Respuesta_826"})
```

I can get the information I need, but if I look for:

```
soup.find('div',{'name':"Pregunta_459Respuesta_841"})
```

I get a None answer even tough I can see the information in the html source code.

Please help me...

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you "see" the information? When you look using a browser, or when you examine a variable in your Python program?

Comment: I can only see it in my browser when I examine the source code or if I print the whole soup and look for that name.

Comment: When I use the 2nd example you posted I get back a `<div>`.  What are you using to download the data?

Comment: Hi, I am only trying to store the text:

    objetives= soup.find('div',{'name':"Pregunta_459Respuesta_841"})

    respuesta_objetives= objetives.p.extract().string.strip()

    print(respuesta_objectives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cofemersimir.gob.mx/mirs/38656')

data = data.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print soup.find('div',{'name':"Pregunta_459Respuesta_841"})
```

I am getting back:

```
<div class="RespMir" name="Pregunta_459Respuesta_841"> <p style="text-align: justify">
                    La regulación de mérito tiene como propósito dar a conocer el cambio de domicilio y horarios de atención de la Delegación de la Secretaría de Relaciones Exteriores en Ciudad Juárez, Chihuahua.
                  </p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, with `BeautifulSoup`, you can also specify a regular expression to match your `name`, which then automatically gives you all of the similar entries:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.cofemersimir.gob.mx/mirs/38656'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = data.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
entries = soup.find_all('div',{'name': re.compile("Pregunta_.*?Respuesta_.*?")})

for entry in entries:
    print '{:25}  {}'.format(entry['name'], entry.text.strip().encode('utf-8')[:20])
```

Which would give you the following, displaying the first 20 characters from each:

```
Pregunta_452Respuesta_826  No
Pregunta_773Respuesta_1399  
Pregunta_453Respuesta_828  No
Pregunta_459Respuesta_841  La regulaci+-ªn de m
Pregunta_462Respuesta_846  La regulaci+-ªn de m
Pregunta_464Respuesta_848  No
Pregunta_465Respuesta_850  No
Pregunta_466Respuesta_852  No
Pregunta_467Respuesta_854  No
```